# How to use a max of 4GB of memory on ElasticSearch?

Tags: macos, elasticsearch, memory-management

I am trying to optimize the use of memory in Elastic Search to use max 4GB on a macOS. I know the following code works on Windows, but when I run it on Mac it doesn't work:

```
./elasticsearch -Xmx4g -Xms4g
```

When running it on Mac it says the following message:

```
ERROR: Parameter [-Xmx4g]does not start with --
```

I have tried to run it without "-" and still does not work.

Any ideas on how to run it on Mac?

Comment: I think this question is better asked at https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Please stick to the internationally agreed SI units system - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units Please use **B** for **bytes** and **b** for **bits**, so one megabyte is 1MB, one gigabyte is 1GB (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte), one gigabit is 1Gb (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit), and if you have to refer to a milllibit for some reason that would be 1mb. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command instead

```
ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4g -Xmx4g" ./bin/elasticsearch
```

or use the jvm.options file mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html)

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html